# Timescaledb continuous aggregate policy not updating back-dated data in range (Error: cannot execute SQL without an outer snapshot or portal)

Tags: timescaledb, continuous-aggregates

I have a table `data` that looks something like this (simplified for the post):

```
|insert_ts          | actual_ts           | group_id| amount|
|2022-02-22 00:01:01| 2022-02-06 05:05:01 | 1       |    100|
```

And a hypertable created as follows:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW hourly_view
    WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT time_bucket('1 hour', actual_ts) as date_hour,
       group_id,
       count(*)                           total,
       avg(amount)                        avg_amount
FROM data
GROUP BY date_hour,
         group_id
WITH NO DATA;
```

With a continuous aggregate policy that looks like this:

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('hourly_view',
                                       start_offset => INTERVAL '1 month',
                                       end_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour',
                                       schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 hour');
```

This seems to work normally with data that is inserted in sequence close to the current timestamp. However, when inserting backdated data that is still within the 1 month range, the data did not appear in the view.

In my case, the `insert_ts` timestamp is telling me when the record was actually inserted. I had records that were inserted between `2022-02-16` and `2022-02-23` but their `actual_ts` (on which I am bucketing the data) was between `2022-02-02` and `2022-02-06`.

I was expecting that the continuous aggregate policy would have everything in sync by the `2022-02-23`, since it should be refreshing 1 month of data every hour. But the data was missing from the aggregate.

I checked the postgresql logs for the 23rd of February and there were the following:

```
2022-02-23 22:01:58.526 UTC [31958] LOG:  refreshing continuous aggregate "hourly_view" in window [ 2022-01-23 23:00:00+00, 2022-02-23 21:00:00+00 ]
2022-02-23 22:01:58.542 UTC [31958] LOG:  job 1002 threw an error
2022-02-23 22:01:58.543 UTC [31958] ERROR:  cannot execute SQL without an outer snapshot or portal
2022-02-23 22:01:58.543 UTC [31958] CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM _timescaledb_internal._materialized_hypertable_4 AS D WHERE D.date_hour >= '2022-01-28 18:00:00+00' AND D.date_hour < '2022-02-23 21:00:00+00' ;"
```

When I ran the following command I the data was refreshed successfully:

```
CALL refresh_continuous_aggregate('vehicle_transit_hourly_view', NULL, NULL);
```

I am currently running Postgres 13 with TimescaleDB 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that should be fixed, depending on what version you are running. There are a couple of related issues. If you are already on release 2.4.1 of TimescaleDB or above, some users have found that the problem persisted because they hadn't run `ALTER EXTENSION` after upgrading.

If this doesn't apply then this may be a different issue and I think your best route might be to raise a new GitHub issue with (if possible) a reproducible example.

Here are the related issue links:

- https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/3496
- https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/pull/3489
- https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/3780

*Transparency: I work for Timescale*

Comment: OK. I just upgraded to 2.6.1. Let's see if it keeps happening.